# LINQ Context cannot get the table in cs

Tags: c#, database, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH5oM.png)

In cs file cannot detect the table and i don't know why it is happen because another page that use the similar code not have the problem but only this page. The page show like that. Please help

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'Table<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error:

Line 18:             var checkid = from user in db.Users
Line 19:                           where user.UserEmail == Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
Line 20:                           select user.UserID;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem code, including `using` statements at the top of your class.

Comment: already add a picture

Comment: You should add this as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of a picture. Should've made that clearer in my original comment, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the program can't find a reference to `System.Data.Linq` in your project. This is not added by default in .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects (and possibly .NET Standard/.NET Core projects). In addition to `System.Linq`, you need to add a reference to this assembly to your project for it to execute properly.

In Visual Studio, you can do this by right-clicking the **References** item in your Solution Explorer, then selecting **Add Reference...** in the context menu that appears. `System.Data.Linq` can then be found in the **Assemblies --> Framework** section.

[image: Selecting Add Reference from References in Solution Explorer]

[image: Reference Manager with System.Data.Linq selected]